# MySQL Search for Value (Integer or String) in a Database Array Field

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have two fields in my MySQL database that are arrays. The datatype is shown as LONGTEXT with a Comment of (DC2Type:array).

For example, the integer values stored in this field would look like this:

`a:4:{i:0;i:9;i:1;i:10;i:2;i:11;i:3;i:12;}`

And the String values would look like this:

`a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Value1";i:1;s:6:"Value2";}`

I need these fields this way so I can store columns that are filterable. E.g. the first one may be age groups so ages 9,10,11,12 are represented.

My query must then get all records that say are relevant for age 10 or in some cases say I want to find those that are 10 and 11.

I've tried the IN and FIND_IN_SET syntaxes but neither is returning any results.

Using `IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE MyField IN (10)
```

Using `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(MyField,'Value1') > 0;
```

I know arrays are probably not the best field to store values in but I didn't want to have separate fields for each AgeGroup e.g. Age1, Age2, etc. or each category e.g Value1, Value2, etc.

Any thoughts on how I can find a value or values from a database array field, please?

Thanks!

Comment: This data is PHP `serialize()` format. There's no simple way to process it directly in MySQL, you need to retrieve all the records, use `unserialize()` and then test for it there.

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` only works with comma-separated values. The values in your field are separated with `;`, not `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pattern match.

Integer:

```
WHERE MyField LIKE '%i:10;%'
```

String:

```
WHERE MyField LIKE '%s:6:"Value1";%'
```

`6` has to be replaced with the length of the string you're searching for.

If you want to search for multiple numbers or strings, you can use a regular expression with alternation:

```
WHERE MyField RLIKE 'i:(10|11);'

WHERE MyField RLIKE 's:(6:"Value1"|10:"LongValue2");'
```

Note that none of these methods can make use of an index on the table. It's generally a bad idea to store arrays in database columns, you should store them as separate rows in a many-to-many table.

Comment: Thanks! Both LIKE and RLIKE work as shown for both integers and strings in MySQL. I'm using Symfony/Doctrine so unfortunately it looks like RLIKE is not supported. I'll have to change the filter criteria to be just single result for now (so we can use LIKE) until we can change the architecture to many-to-many instead of serialized arrays. Appreciate the quick response and assist.

Comment: `RLIKE` is another name for `REGEXP`.

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` for the multiple case, since it doesn't have alternation. You would have to write `MyField LIKE '%i:10;%' OR MyField LIKE '%i:11;%'`

Comment: [Symfony Regex](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html)